# android fragment fall on each other

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, onclicklistener

cheers...
(edited)
i checked many kinds of similar post like this, but i cant work it out

scenario : 
2 fragment = fragment a and b
1 button (using onclick method)

what i tried to do :
calling the fragment b from fragment a using onlick method with button

tried browsing loooooooottttt of post in here, but yet still not understand how to do it properly,especially the part about the change "container" from the xml 
(worked)

its working but now i am confused why the fragment fall on each other when i click the button
please help me, i am at my limit

first fragment :

```
package com.example.fabio.tabdrawer;
import....

public class Menu_Berita extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    final FrameLayout mRelative = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.berita_layout, container, false);
//this fragment part which i changed above
    final Button button_next = (Button) mRelative.findViewById(R.id.button_next);
    button_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new Menu_riwayat()).commit();
            //still not working properly, error in logcat

        }

    });
    return mRelative;
}}
```

xml for first fragment:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="clip_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="test1"
        android:id="@+id/text_test1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_test1"
        android:entries="@array/spinner_resiko_string"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Resiko"
        android:id="@+id/text_test2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_test2"
        android:entries="@array/spinner_syariah_string"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

second fragment :

```
public class Menu_Riwayat extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    final FrameLayout mRelative = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.riwayat_layout, container, false);


    return Relative;
}}
```

xml for second fragment :

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">
 <ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="clip_horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="129dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

(logcat removed)

screnshot :
[fragment fall on each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOCX7.png)

Comment: you should do new Menu_riwayat() instead of Menu_riwayat....which will give you new instance of fragment of type Menu_riwayat

Comment: Set the proper container to replace the View in and follow Shadow Droid's directions too. Also, you're dealing with nested Fragments here. You're replacing a Fragment within a Fragment, would be more simple to host your scrollview in an activity and call your activity's replaceFragment() from your fragment A, using Broadcast Receivers or Events (EventBus).

Comment: @ShadowDroid i changed it to new Menu_riwayat(), and i got IllegalStateException error, system stated that ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: i tried to wrap the scrollview with FrameLayout, its working, but the result was its like the 2 fragment fall on each other. any idea how to fix it ? (i edited the post already)